# ajax form is not posting data to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

With the help of Stackoverflow, I am learning the website design. Recently, I wrote following code for sending data from HTML form using Ajax.  The code is clearly checking the error but sending the PHP message.  I have used ajax google libraries: **http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js**

the Ajax code is given below.

```
function Submit(e) {
  // form submittion using ajax.
  var name = $("#name").val();
  var place = $("#place").val();
  var message = $("#message").val();

  // error checking
  if ($("#name").val() == "") {
    $("#name").focus();
    $("#error").html("Enter the Name.");
    return false;
  } else if ($("#place").val() == "") {
    $("#place").focus();
    $("#error").html("Enter the Place.");
    return false;
  } else if ($("#message").val() == "") {
    $("#message").focus();
    $("#error").html("Enter the message.");
    return false;
  } else if ($(name != '' && place != '' && message != '')) {
    $("#error").html("Form submitted successfully.")
    $("#form")[0].reset();

    // on successful, data submission using php
    $.post("xxx.xyz/abc.php", {
      name: name,
      place: place,
      message: message
    }, function(data) {
      $("#error").append(data);
    });
  }
}
```

I have checked few Questions & answers, but unable to find correct one. Please help me. What I request is to pass the entered data to php.

Comment: Try removing the `$` from `else if($(name != '' && place != '' && message != ''))`. Should be `else if(name != '' && place != '' && message != '')`

Comment: Have you checked the console? Any errors there?

Comment: Where is you `<form>` code, and where you bind the form submit to your `function Submit(e){ }`

Comment: @sean   <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="  ">
<div id="error"></div>
 Full Name:      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /> <br>
 Place:    <input type="text" name="place" id="place" /><br>
  Message:       <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="23" rows="5" /><br>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onClick="Submit(event)" />
 </form>

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax like this instead of `$.post("xxx.xyz/abc.php"`

```
$.ajax({
    url: "xxx.xyz/abc.php",
    type: "post",
    data : {
     name: name, place: place, message: message
   },
    success: function(data){    
         $("#error").append(data); 
    }
});
```

Comment: $.post is a shorthand for $.ajax

Comment: Need to explain why, as from [`$.post` docs - *This is a shorthand Ajax function*](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: $.post support only success callback, but in $.ajax support success, failure and beforesend and complete callbacks. If any error we cant get anything in $.post

Comment: But your example doesn't show the `failure`, `beforesend`, and `complete` callbacks. Your example is basically the same as the OP's `$.post` code. You need to add the why, and update your example, to improve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Call your Submit function on your form submit and remove your last else if condition. After successful data validation use ajax method to post your data.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things I'm noticing here.

1. If you are using the submit feature on a form you are not preventing
   the default action.
2. Your last else if statement isn't needed as you
   check for errors and return false which won't send the form.

I'd also recommend only sending a success message if the send was actually successful, otherwise send and error message.

I've created a fiddle which shows you how to handle the problem using a form. If you aren't using a form this may be irrelevant.

As of jquery 3.0 [.then()](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) has been removed in favor of [$.done()](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)
 which should be used instead for a success callback.

https://jsfiddle.net/a9m2699s/1/

Here is the new submit method. Note: It can be refactored more but for the sake of keeping it close to the question we'll leave it at that.

```
 function Submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

  // form submittion using ajax.
  var form = $(e.currentTarget);
  var name = $("#name").val();
  var place = $("#place").val();
  var message = $("#message").val();

  // error checking
  if ($("#name").val() == "") {
    $("#name").focus();
    $("#error").html("Enter the Name.");
    return false;
  } else if ($("#place").val() == "") {
    $("#place").focus();
    $("#error").html("Enter the Place.");
    return false;
  } else if ($("#message").val() == "") {
    $("#message").focus();
    $("#error").html("Enter the message.");
    return false;
  }

  // on successful, data submission using php
  $.post(form.attr('action'), {
    name: name,
    place: place,
    message: message
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    // handle successful response here.
    $("#error").html("Form submitted successfully.")
    form[0].reset();
  })
  .fail(function(err) {
    // handle err here.
  });
}

// test action
$('form').on('submit', Submit)
```

Comment: It is working but with the successful message, the fields to be blank / refresh

Comment: @scm The form element doesn't have an ID on it in the fiddle. You can either place the ID on the form or you can check this fiddle out: https://jsfiddle.net/a9m2699s/1/ where I reference the form that you are submitting.

Comment: @Dennia, where is the php url to be placed " xxx.xyz/abc.php"

Comment: @scm If you are using a form it would read from the action attribute on the form. If not replace this line `$.post(form.attr('action'), {` with this: `$.post('xxx.xyz/abc.php', {`